# Getting exception "basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file"

Tags: c++, linux, ifstream

While trying to perform following code:

```
void XMLRulesReader::ReadRulesFromFile(vector<Rule> *SysRulesP, vector <TagInRule> *ConnectedTagsP, vector <TagsGroup> *SysTagGroups)

{

    xml_document<> doc;
    xml_node<> * root_node;
    int value=0;
    string fileName;
try
{

    // Read the xml file into a vector
    fileName = "/home/root/LogiTrackV2/Log/Rules.xml";


    ifstream theFile (fileName.c_str());

    if (theFile.is_open())
    {

       vector<char> buffer((istreambuf_iterator<char>(theFile)),    
                istreambuf_iterator<char>());       
       buffer.push_back('\0');

     // Parse the buffer using the xml file parsing library into doc 
       doc.parse<0>(&buffer[0]);

    // Find our root node
      root_node = doc.first_node("rules");

      if (root_node==NULL)
        return;


      for (xml_node<> * rule_node = root_node->first_node("rule"); rule_node;
                rule_node = rule_node->next_sibling("rule"))
      { 
        AddNewRule(rule_node, SysRulesP, ConnectedTagsP,SysTagGroups);          
      }

      theFile.close();


    }


}
catch (exception& e)
{



    throw e;
}
```

}

I'm getting exception: "basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file" when executing the line: 
vector buffer((istreambuf_iterator(theFile)),                 istreambuf_iterator());

The thing is that the first time the above function is called it is being executed fine, but in the second time it is called then it throws the above exception.
Another weird thing is that if I run the program several times, it throws the exception in the first 3-4 times, but it work fine afterwards...

any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Why catch exceptions if you are just re-throwing them?

Comment: As for the problem, have you tried running in a debugger to see *where* the exception is thrown from?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've added the exact line which causes the excpetion ( vector<char> buffer((istreambuf_iterator<char>(theFile)),    
                    istreambuf_iterator<char>());)

Comment: I think it has to do with the content that's being read. What is inside that XML?

Comment: Very late to the party here, but the problem was possibly related to the old GCC bug described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371956/unexpected-exception-in-stdifstream)