# Unexpected exception in std::ifstream

Tags: c++, iostream

Experimenting with I/O I get an exception where no exception should have been thrown:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("/tmp");
    std::cout << "Exception Flags: " << f.exceptions() << std::endl;
    if(f >> std::ws) std::cout << "This will not succeed" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "Ok - it fails" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the output is:

```
Exception Flags: 0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
  what():  basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file
Aborted
```

g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2

**Edit**

The test is supposed to fail without exception:

From 27.5.5.4 basic_ios flags functions

> void clear(iostate state = goodbit);
>
> 4 Postcondition: If rdbuf()!=0 then state == rdstate(); otherwise rdstate()==(state | ios_base::badbit).
>
> 5 Effects: If ((state | (rdbuf() ? goodbit : badbit)) &
>   exceptions()) == 0, returns. Otherwise, the function throws an
>   object fail of class basic_ios::failure (27.5.3.1.1), constructed with
>   implementation-defined argument values.
>
> void setstate(iostate state);
>
> 6 Effects: Calls clear(rdstate() |
>   state) (which may throw basic_ios::failure (27.5.3.1.1)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug, and clang v3.4 with libc++ [doesn't exhibit this behaviour](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65939ef30180b800); GCC 4.8's libstdc++ [still does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96a0b8d78b631445).

From the libstdc++ source and the text of the exception, I'd say that [`basic_ios::clear`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++/api/a01050_source.html#l00041) is not catching exceptions thrown from down the call stack and applying the "are exception flags in play?" logic before potentially rethrowing them.

It was already raised last year as [bug 53984](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53984).

Comment: Side note: with clang the result is: "This will not succeed" having 'f >> std::ws' and "Ok - it fails" having 'f >> x', where x is an integer.

Comment: @Dieter: Yep; see link in first para