# catch an open exception

Tags: c++, exception, io

I have this code and just wondered why it's not throwing an exception (or in which case it should do).

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/) :

> If the function fails to open a file, the failbit state flag is set for the stream (which may throw ios_base::failure if that state flag was registered using member exceptions).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::ofstream fs;

  try {
    fs.open("/non-existing-root-file");
  } catch (const std::ios_base::failure& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  if (fs.is_open())
   std::cout << "is open" << std::endl;
  else
   std::cout << "is not open" << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not follow the rabbit trail [all of the way down](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/)
You need to tell it you want exceptions by using `std::ios::exceptions`. Without doing this, it indicates failure through the `failbit` state flag.

```
// ios::exceptions
#include <iostream>     // std::cerr
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  std::ifstream file;
  ///next line tells the ifstream to throw on fail
  file.exceptions ( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
  try {
    file.open ("test.txt");
    while (!file.eof()) file.get();
    file.close();
  }
  catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception opening/reading/closing file\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And of course, you _never_ want to have `failbit` triggering an exception, since it is the only way you can detect end of file too.

Comment: I don't know why you would even need an exception. You could always throw your own if it makes sense for your code organization and flow.

Comment: It's occasionally useful to have an exception on `badbit`; that should only be set in case of a hardware problem (disk error, lost connection, etc.).  For the others: `failbit` is used in the recognition of end of file, and `eofbit` can be set even if no problem has occurred.

Comment: Watch out for implementation bugs, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20372624/560648

Answer (score 0):

I dont think fstream throws an exception on failure to open file. you have to check that with bool fstream::is_open().

Answer (score 0):

You would need to register the `failbit` flag using `std::ios::exceptions()` for it to throw, which you haven't done.